# squid still caching

Tags: squid

I have set this

```
maximum_object_size 0 KB
minimum_object_size 0 KB
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
no_cache deny all
```

but when I do test for the caching

```
curl -x ip1:3128 http://blabla.com/iptest.php
sleep 5
curl -x ip2:55555 http://blabla.com/iptest.php
```

both will return only the fist ip (ip1)

If the sleep is bigger that 30, it will show the ip2 too

LATER EDIT:
I see that the problem is if you hit the squid with 2 connsecutive requests it will always exit on the internet with the ip used on the first request

Comment: Which is your curl version ?

Comment: is also happening in firefox... so I'm pretty sure that isn't from curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `cache deny all` instead of `no_cache deny all`?

Comment: tried that too and doesn't work

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly: This is a single instance of squid answering on two different IP addresses and two different ports? Have you checked the access log on blabla.com to see if there is indeed only one request?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained very clear. I made 2 requests, one after the other on a ip verification page on. The second request is served from the cache instead of  sending to the verification page

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. What do you test exactly? What is ip1:3128 and what is ip2:55555? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: made a later edit "I see that the problem is if you hit the squid with 2 connsecutive requests it will always exit on the internet with the ip used on the first request". Thanks for the interest

Comment: So the problem is not squid but your test. You are starting with wrong assumptions. If you access squid on one ip address, there is no guarantee that squid itself will fetch the requested data using that same ip address. This is not a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Oliver's answer, you can also put this to your squid.conf

```
refresh_pattern . 0 100% 0
```

Comment: tried that too and doesn't work